# SARIMAX create a simulation

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to use this function on python to simulate the SARIMAX model that i have build,
`statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.simulate`
the purpose is to do a monte carlo simulation using that model

the problem happens when i try to put initial_state on the function using data that i already have

I already tried to not use the initial_state and the result of the simulation seems fine, but the initial point is not what i expected. when i try to put an initial_state, the simulation results grows exponentially.

i use daily precipitation data from 2017- 2019

```
#Define the test model using another set of data, but the same order.
testMdl = smt.SARIMAX(rain_df_daily.y, order = (5, 3, 0), seasonal_order=(1,1,2,12),enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)

#Set initial state 
#testMdl.initialize_known(rain_df_daily[:'2018-01-01'].y.mean,rain_df_daily[:'2018-01-01'].y.std)
testMdl.initialize_known(sarima_results.predicted_state[:,-2], 
                         sarima_results.predicted_state_cov[:,:,-2])

#Initialize the test model with the coefficients from the fit model:
testMdl = testMdl.filter(sarima_results.params)
#Seems you can also use .smooth() to initialize coefficients, but have not looked into the difference
#exoCopy = exoCopy.smooth(fitMdl.params)

samples = pd.DataFrame(columns = range(0,50)) #initialize obs. sample df
for sample in range(0, 50): #For each sample

    #samples[sample] = testMdl.simulate(24, initial_state=mdlExo.predicted_state[:,-1])
    samples[sample] = testMdl.simulate(40, initial_state = rain_df_daily['2018-02-21':].y)
```

i expect the result will be close to the predicted mean

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your model are the specified order parameters rather than the initial values for simulation.

E.g. a simpler model fitted on rainfall data

[Rainfall data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSEdY.png)

```
model = SARIMAX(df, 
            order=(1, 0, 1), 
            trend='n',
            seasonal_order=(1, 2, 1, 5),
            enforce_stationarity=False,
            enforce_invertibility=False).fit()
model.forecast(60).plot()
```

produces the results

[Simpler fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO0Ze.png)

And the simulation

```
samples = []
for sample in range(50): 
    samples.append(model.simulate(30, initial_state=model.predicted_state[:, -1]))

sns.lineplot(data=samples)
```

results in

[Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgU44.png)

This is for sure not a great model but the results are not that far away from the prediction mean.